# Unable to send parameters to servlet on form submit through javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, jsp, servlets

I have a HTML form as follows:-

```
<form name="login" id="login" action="<%=application.getContextPath()%>/GoogleLogin" method="get">
<input type=hidden id="firstName"/>
</form>
```

I am setting the values of this hidden input type in javascript and submitting the form to servlet as follows:-

```
    <script>
    document.getElementById("firstName").value="XYZ";
    document.getElementById("login").submit();
    <script>
```

My form is getting submitted but I am not able to get the request parameter "firstName".

```
http://localhost:8080/Login/GoogleLogin?
```

Thank you for your time and consideration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `name` attribute to the input field -

```
<input type="hidden" id="firstName" name="firstName" />
```

then you'll be able to get the request parameter using `firstName`.

Comment: Whoaa!! Thankyou It worked. But what why I need to add name attriute?

Comment: @saumyaraj: Because when you submit a form, the `name` attribute's value is used by the server to identify a parameter's value.